# Stop validation after first found invalid field in parsley.js

Tags: validation, parsley.js

I'm implementing a registration form, and the design for it does not work together with all fields having an error marker at the same time. (We show a small speech balloon, above the field)

I want the validation to stop after first found error, making the user see one problem at a time.

According to documentation, the data-parsley-priority-enabled option might be what i'm looking for, but since its default true, i guess i don't get it to work because all fields have the same priority?

Is there a way to specify priority per field? As I understand it, its defined per constraint (validation method?).

Or do i need to implement a unique custom validator per field to get the desired effect?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're expecting is not implemented in Parsley. And I think it won't because it is very specific. You'll have to implement it yourself, and this is rather easy:

```
var formInstance = $('#yourform').parsley(), result;
for (i = 0; i < formInstance.fields.length; i++) {
  result = formInstance.fields[i].validate();

  // field is valid if result is `true` or `[]`
  // if we have here [Violation] there is an error, no need to go further
  if (true !== result && result.length)
    break;
}
```

It might look something like that.

Hope that helped